# ¿Cómo aregar elementos a documento XML utilizando serializacion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde debo serializar una clase en un Json, en esta clase existe una propiedad que es un arreglo  del tipo System.Xml.XmlNode[]

Propiedad

```
private System.Xml.XmlNode[] anyField;

public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
```

escribo el siguiente codiigo pero me dice:NO SE PUEDE CREAR UNA INSTANCIA DE LA CLASE O INTERFAZ ABSTRACTA XmlNode

```
CanonicalizationMethod= new CanonicalizationMethodType
                          {
                               Any = new System.Xml.XmlNode[1] 
                               {
                                   new System.Xml.XmlNode
                                   {

                                   }
                               }
                          }
```

Comment: Veo la variable `anyField` que es de ámbito privado (no es una propiedad), lo que si entiendo que la propiedad `Any` no está aceptando una instancia "para un elemento" de tu array de tipo `XmlNode`, ¿Quieres agregarle un elemento? o ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Tienes razon ..Ya edite mi pregunta...

Comment: ¿Cómo te fué con la respuesta que publiqué?

Comment: Hola Davlio... Soy nuevo en esto de crear documentos JSON o XML desde codigo y segun lo que e podido observar lo que nesecito es  insertar un nuevo nodo  dentro de esas lineas de codigo, (dentro de esas lineas por que ese codigo forma parte de donde creo el documento , solo debo agregar un nuevo nodo sin crear un nuevo documento )

Comment: ¿Porqué crear una nueva pregunta y no considerar editarla? [¿Cómo agregar elemento a documento XML en tiempo de ejecución?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101796) . Indicas que quieres serializar una clase a una estructura XML, entonces deberías agregar el XML esperado tras serializar.

Answer (score 2):

El error indica que la clase [`XmlNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) es abstracta y por ende no podrás generar una instancia de dicha clase.

---

Para generar un nodo podrías usar el método `CreateNode` de la clase `XmlDocument`, por ello te preguntaba en los comentarios que querías hacer.

Por ejemplo:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var node = doc.CreateNode("element", "name", "namespaceURI");

CanonicalizationMethod= new CanonicalizationMethodType
{
    Any = new[]
    {
        node    
    };
}
```

Te recomiendo que revises la referencia y verifiques las sobre cargas del método `CreateNode`.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Métodos XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmldocument_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hola Davlio ...La forma que muestras no la puedo aplicar usando la serializacion de la clase