# ¿Cómo firmar documento XML con XMLDsig?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Desarrollo una aplicación donde serializo una clase en un documento XML y nesecito firmarlo electronicamente.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: por nuevo nodos, te refieres a agregar elementos nuevos en el XML o agregar nodos al xsd? la verdad no me queda claro que es lo nuevo que quieres agregar..

Comment: Me refiero a agregar elementos nuevos en el XML..ya edito el Post

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC leyendo tu pregunta ahora entiendo, el problema que tenías era otro.

Comment: @Davlio Puedes editar y proponer tu respuesta..igual la marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esas clases están incluidas en el espacio de nombres `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` para firmar o un documento XML o parte de él con un certificado.
Haz una prueba con este ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
using System.Xml;

public class SignXML
{

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new CspParameters object to specify
            // a key container.
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";

            // Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            // Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");

            // Sign the XML document. 
            SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);

            Console.WriteLine("XML file signed.");

            // Save the document.
            xmlDoc.Save("test.xml");



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }


    // Sign an XML file. 
    // This document cannot be verified unless the verifying 
    // code has the key with which it was signed.
    public static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA Key)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
        if (Key == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Key");

        // Create a SignedXml object.
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

        // Add the key to the SignedXml document.
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        // Append the element to the XML document.
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

    }
}
```

Ejemplo obtenido de 
[How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx)

Rellena tu clase con los atributos que deseas, serializa a XML y ese resultado lo firmas con el método descrito. Ya el proceso de firma te calcula y escribe esos nodos de `CanonicalizationMethodType` por ejemplo. Fíjate que el namespace de esa clase es http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el código de ejemplo

```
    public static void SetearFactura()
    {
        XmlDocument docA = new XmlDocument();
        docA.LoadXml("<Libros><Libro titulo='tituloA' /><Libro titulo='tituloB' /></Libros>");
        var nodeA = docA.CreateElement("version");

        XmlDocument docB = new XmlDocument();
        docB.LoadXml("<Alumnos><Alumno nombre='pedro' edad='22'/><Alumno nombre='pablo' edad='28'/></Alumnos>");
        var nodeB = docB.CreateElement("Alumno");
        var nombre = docB.CreateAttribute("nombre");
        var edad = docB.CreateAttribute("edad");

        nombre.Value = "susana";
        edad.Value = "26";

        nodeB.Attributes.Append(nombre);
        nodeB.Attributes.Append(edad);            

        var CanonicalizationMethod = new CanonicalizationMethodType
        {
            Any = new System.Xml.XmlNode[2]
            {
                nodeA,
                nodeB
            },
            Algorithm = "666"
        };
    }
```

La propiedad `Any` se utiliza para poder incorporar nuevas estructuras de XMLs que tienen definiciones distintas. Por eso en este ejemplo te muestro que de dos `XmlDocuments` distintos se pueden generar nuevos nodos que se van a incorporar a tu objeto de `CanonicalizationMethodType`.